# HTML/CSS: Can't figure out how to get a divider in a box

Tags: html, css

I'm very new at this, so sorry if my code is a little messy. I'm trying to create a job search page where the results will show a bar like this:

[image]

I've kinda got it, except I can't get that divider in between the PREV, 1 to 100, and NEXT. Mine looks like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="results">
    <a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/">Prev<a/>
    <a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/" >1 to 100 of 179<a/>
    <a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/" >Next<a/>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.results {
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

I've tried making a results class for every link, but then I end up getting one big box and 3 little boxes around each link.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.results {
color: black;
border: 1px solid lightgrey;
width: 300px;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-left: 60px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
  display:flex;
}

.results a {
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

.a, .c {
  flex:1;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  text-align:center;
}

.b {
  flex:2;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  text-align:center;
  border-right:1px solid lightgray;
  border-left:1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="results">
    <div class="a"><a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/">&lt; Prev<a/></div>
   <div class="b"> <a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/" >1 to 100 of 179<a/></div>
   <div class="c"> <a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/" >Next ><a/></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Although I'm not sure what flex does just yet but I'm sure I'll learn that at some point.

Comment: the flex property sets the length of each flex item relative to other flex items in the container. That is why the middle section is double the size.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put this in very simple table. I think it should be good enough solution for your need.

Something like this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tskoe3v5/)

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/">Prev</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/" >1 to 100 of 17</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/" >Next</a>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

With CSS with base like this

```
.results {
color: black;
border: 1px solid lightgrey;
width: 300px;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-left: 60px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your case is simple enough, don't no fancy flexbox or anything.

```css
.results {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  /* width: 300px; removed */
  display: inline-block;  /* Added */
  /* padding:5px; moved to the children (<a>) */
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}


/* Added */
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* giving the second child left and right border to mimic dividers */

.results>a:nth-child(2) {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-left: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="results">
  <a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/">Prev</a>
  <a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/">1 to 100 of 179</a>
  <a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/">Next</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your closing tags on the `<a>` links are wrong. They should look like `</a>` with the slash before the a. Once you update those, you can place the `<a>` links into individual divs:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div><a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/">Prev</a></div>
  <div><a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/">1 to 100 of 179</a></div>
  <div><a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/">Next</a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  float: left;
}

#container {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

#container div {
  padding: 8px 24px;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

#container div:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many factors that are needed:

1. Your elements  were badly closed
2. You need to be more specific to what elements you should apply the CSS

These are just the most notable, you need more CSS information. Much success.

```css
.results {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.results a {
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 150px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="results">
    <a href="#">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" >1 to 100 of 179</a>
    <a href="#" >Next</a>
  </div>
```

```html
<div class="results">
    <a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/">Prev<a/>
    <a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/" >1 to 100 of 179<a/>
    <a href="https://gregslist--farahgus10.repl.co/" >Next<a/>
</div>
```